# Data sort specific field

Tags: excel, vba

We have a button in our spreadsheet that once pressed, should unprotect the sheet, data sort (oldest to newest date order) a specific column (F) then protect the sheet. The data within the sheet is a table called Branch_Data.

```vb
Sub SingleLevelSort()

Worksheets("Portfolio Tracker").Unprotect Password:="XXXXX"

Worksheets("Portfolio Tracker").Sort.SortFields.Clear

Range("A2:BA5000").Sort Key1:=Range("F3"), Header:=xlYes

Worksheets("Portfolio Tracker").Protect Password:="XXXXX", AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, DrawingObjects:=True, Scenarios:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=True

End Sub
```

I get

> run-time error 1004. Application-defined or object-defined error

at

```
.Range("A2:AX5000").Sort Key1:=.Range("F3"), Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: Error is on which line though?

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific when referring to ranges:

```vb
Sub SingleLevelSort()
    Const PW As String = "XXXXX" 'use Const for fixed values
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Portfolio Tracker")
        .Unprotect Password:=PW
        .Sort.SortFields.Clear
        'scope ranges to specific sheet
        .Range("A2:BA5000").Sort Key1:=.Range("F3"), Header:=xlYes
        .Protect Password:=PW, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
                  AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, DrawingObjects:=True, _
                  Scenarios:=False, AllowDeletingRows:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for responding. I tried this code but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error - Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications - 400.

I'm assuming, I could just copy your code and just updated the password and nothing else needs to change?

Comment: It looks like on both our code, it errors out at this line:
```.Range("A2:AX5000").Sort Key1:=.Range("F3"), Header:=xlYes```

I get run-time error 1004. Application-defined or object-defined error